# Laravel form doesn't return https url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm using [Laravel Form](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html) along with `https`, but I'm having hard times with the `Form` component. For some reason `Laravel` always return `http://` protocol for all the urls generated by the `Form` component.

This is my `.env`:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https://example.com
```

**header.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'boilerplate.logout', 'method' => 'post', 'id' => 'logout-form']) !!}
<button type="submit" class="btn nav-link d-flex align-items-center logout px-2" data-question="{{ __('boilerplate::layout.logoutconfirm') }}">
    <span class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off hidden-xs pr-1"></span>
</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**routes/boilerplate.php**

```
Route::post('logout', [LoginController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
```

The form should return:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://example.com/admin/logout" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="logout-form">
```

but I get:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://example.com/admin/logout" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="logout-form">
```

I found a similar question, and one user has proposed to add:

```
\URL::forceScheme('https');
```

within `AppServiceProvider.php` but, I would like to know why there is the following behavior. Is this an issue of the framework or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: are you behind a proxy? is the address you are accessing `https`?

Comment: @lagbox yes, I'm using a proxy and I was able to fix this updating the nginx configuration, in particular I added this: `fastcgi_param  HTTPS "on";`

Answer (score 2):

Because laravel doesn't care about the `APP_URL` for the `scheme`, laravel check if the `https` is support in the server, if you're in production server and the `https` has been implemented it will automatically use the `https` protocol

Laravel relay heavily at `symfony http foundation` in the [URLGenerator.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/search?q=forceScheme) that you can see if the `$forceScheme` is `null` it will fallback to `$this->request->getScheme()` which is instance of (symfony http foundation) `Request.php`

If you look the `Request.php` of `symfony http foundation` you can see methods `(isSecure and getScheme)`

```
public function isSecure()
{
    if ($this->isFromTrustedProxy() && $proto = $this->getTrustedValues(self::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO)) {
        return \in_array(strtolower($proto[0]), ['https', 'on', 'ssl', '1'], true);
    }

    $https = $this->server->get('HTTPS');

    return !empty($https) && 'off' !== strtolower($https);
}

public function getScheme()
{
    return $this->isSecure() ? 'https' : 'http';
}
```

as you can see that in `isSecure` method it check if the `request` is from `trusted proxies` or if the `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` is `on`.

By setting `URL::forceScheme('https');` it will force to be `https` and not used the `$this->request->getScheme()`.